# Binary images have related spectra

Tags: image-processing

I do not understand the meaning of "related spectra" in binary images. It is said the 3 pictures below have "related spectra". Could anyone tell me what it is? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: it would help if you'd provide any context. I'm sure you have not dreamed that tonight. Where did you read this? Who said this? Link and quote the source...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math and not programming. You might have better luck at the signal processing or math stack exchange.